# Is this a JAVA_OPT JVM Flag?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm-arguments

I am reading a tutorial [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/Administration_Console_User_Guide-Accessing_the_Console.html) on how to get the jboss admin console to work - it says the following;

> The Console, as well as the JMX and JBossWS consoles, are deployed
>   "on-demand" by default. This means that the consoles are deployed when
>   the user requests access. This deferred deployment strategy minimizes
>   the overall server boot time. This feature can be disabled, however,
>   by passing the following property to the server start command:
>
> /run.sh -Djboss.as.deployment.ondemand=false Once the server is
>   started, simply point your browser of choice to:
>
> `http://localhost:8080/admin-console` JBoss AS binds its services to
>   localhost (127.0.0.1) by default, instead of binding to all available
>   interfaces (0.0.0.0). This was primarily done for security reasons
>   because of concerns of users going to production without having
>   secured their servers properly. To enable remote access by binding
>   JBoss services to a particular interface, simply start the JBoss AS
>   server with the -b option. To bind to all available interfaces and
>   re-enable the legacy behaviour use -b 0.0.0.0. If the server is
>   started with the -b option, you will have to alter the URL
>   accordingly.

Does this mean that to get the console to display I need to pass in a jvm arg using JAVA_OPT for value of `-Djboss.as.deployment.ondemand=false`

Similarly - the standalone.sh is initiated using the following - `./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &` how does this affect what the document is telling me to do.

Basically, I really don't understand whats going on :/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using an environment variable for the argument. Every other java when ran will be passed this.

If I understand what you are saying, then you need to do something like

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.as.deployment.ondemand=false -b 0.0.0.0
```

If this doesn't work. Try flipping around the arguments.